# Crop and scale MTLTexture

Tags: ios, metal

Can I create a new `MTLTexture` of dimensions `w2/h2` of an existing `MTLTexture` region `x1/y1/w1/h1`?

PS: I thought about using `MTLTexture.buffer?.makeTexture` but the offset needs to be 64 bytes. Why?

Comment: If you need scaling/resampling, you might consider writing your own kernel or vertex/fragment functions, or use an `MPSImageLanczosScale` kernel from the MetalPerformanceShaders framework if your target is iOS 9.0+.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might do this with `MPSImageLanczosScale`. Note that `sourceRegion` is expressed in the pixel coordinate system of the source texture, and `destRegion` should be equal to the full area of the destination texture (note that it specifically doesn't account for the origin of the destination region):

```
let scaleX = Double(destRegion.size.width) / Double(sourceRegion.size.width)
let scaleY = Double(destRegion.size.height) / Double(sourceRegion.size.height)
let translateX = Double(-sourceRegion.origin.x) * scaleX
let translateY = Double(-sourceRegion.origin.y) * scaleY
let filter = MPSImageLanczosScale(device: device)
var transform = MPSScaleTransform(scaleX: scaleX, scaleY: scaleY, translateX: translateX, translateY: translateY)
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
withUnsafePointer(to: &transform) { (transformPtr: UnsafePointer<MPSScaleTransform>) -> () in
    filter.scaleTransform = transformPtr
    filter.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: sourceTexture, destinationTexture: destTexture)
}
commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

If you need to read the destination texture on the CPU, you can wait until the command buffer completes, or add a completed handler to the command buffer to receive an async callback when the resampling work is done. Otherwise, you can encode additional work in the command buffer and use the destination texture immediately. If you're going to be repeatedly scaling textures, you should keep a single instance of `MPSImageLanczosScale` around instead of repeatedly creating instances of it.

Comment: Although I was hoping to just reference the buffer instead of creating a copy I guess this will still suffice as the texture remains in GPU memory.

Comment: If the target texture has the same dimensions as the source region, you can achieve what you want using a blit command encoder. I just assumed the scaling part was essential, in which case you can't get by without some kind of resampling.

Comment: @warrenm I don't mean to ressurect the dead, but any idea why this doesn't work with MPSImageScale for those of us who want something a little faster than the Lanczos Filter? Perhaps it's necessary to write a naive linear scale compute kernel on our own? It would appear to me that this should be something MPS already had..

Comment: The only reason I didn't suggest `MPSImageScale` is that it didn't exist at the time.

Comment: This sounded promising but  `withUnsafePointer` fails with `validateComputeFunctionArguments:829: failed assertion 'Compute Function(lanczosHorizontalScale): writes texture (dest[1]) whose usage (0x01) doesn't specify MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite (0x02)'`

Comment: To address the issue above, need to ensure you specify `textureDescriptor.usage = [.shaderRead, .shaderWrite]` when creating your destination texture.

Answer (score 5):

`MPSImageScale` can't be used directly because it is an abstract class. The concrete classes are `MPSImageLanczosScale` and `MPSImageBilinearScale`.