# How to crop the texture while using custom shaders?

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I tried cropping the `MTLTexture` using default filters provided by apple using `clipRect` and `offset` properties and it works fine with the live video filtering.

But for custom filters(Using `custom shaders`) the properties `clipRect` and `offset` has no effect in cropping the `MTLTexture` and I tried to crop using the `MPSImageLanczosScale` referring [Crop and scale MTLTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970644/crop-and-scale-mtltexture).

```
func encodeWithTransform(to commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, sourceTexture: MTLTexture, destinationTexture: MTLTexture, transform: MPSScaleTransform) {

   var newTransform = transform

   withUnsafePointer(to: &newTransform) { (transformPtr: UnsafePointer<MPSScaleTransform>) -> () in

       lanczosScaleFilter.scaleTransform = transformPtr
       lanczosScaleFilter.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: sourceTexture, destinationTexture: newCroppingTexture)
       self.imageFilter.encode(to: commandBuffer!, sourceTexture: newCroppingTexture, destinationTexture: destinationTexture, cropRect: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(uiscreenWidth) / 4, sourceTexture.height), offset : CGPoint(x: 0 / scale, y:0))
    }
}
```

As you can see here we are trying to crop the texture and then encode the filter which is a two way operation and the process is very slow.

But if the filter is applied without cropping the texture the performance is very smooth. The encode method looks like this.

```
    blur.clipRect = cropRect
    blur.offset = MPSOffset(x: Int(offset.x), y: Int(offset.y), z: 0)

    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSizeMake(10, 10, 1)
    let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSizeMake(destinationTexture.width / threadsPerThreadgroup.width, sourceTexture.height / threadsPerThreadgroup.height, 1)

    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState!)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(sourceTexture, at: 0)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(destinationTexture, at: 1)

    commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    commandEncoder.endEncoding()

    autoreleasepool {
        var inplaceTexture = destinationTexture

        blur.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, inPlaceTexture: &inplaceTexture, fallbackCopyAllocator: nil)
    }
```

There is no need to use the blur filter for encoding. But I added this hopping that it would crop using `clipRect` and `offset` properties but had no luck.

So if anyone has better solution may be modifying the texture rect inside the custom shader methods that would be helpful. Also if anyone would suggest me how apple does it with `clipRect` and `offset` properties that would help me.

Comment: Absolute fastest way would be to not use compute shaders at all, but instead setup a rendering pipeline and modify texture coordinates either in the vertex or fragment shader

Comment: @Gary I'm new to metal(also graphics). So if you would suggest me how to do this with some code that would be really helpful to me. Although I have a doubt, if you use only vertex/fragment shader how do you apply the custom filters? Thanks.

Comment: With vertex/fragment shaders you could create pretty much any filters you want, e.g. Brad Larson's GPUImage is all done with vertex/fragment shaders (all in glsl, but easy to convert to metal shading language). If your new to graphics I'd recommend sticking with compute shaders though (quiet a bit of work and understanding involved), but if you want to go down the rendering pipeline way, I suppose Apples sample code MetalVideoCapture would be an illustration of using a rendering pipeline with video.

Comment: @Gary finally I was able to apply the filter using vertex and fragment shader. Your suggestion helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary why do you say not apply compute shaders, I hear they are generally faster than vertex and fragment shaders in render pipeline?

Comment: There is overhead associated with compute shaders that is not present with the standard rendering pipeline. If what you want to do fits naturally into the standard pipeline and you do it efficiently it will be faster, but you can profile both versions and see for yourself, I’ve noticed up to a 2-fold speed increases even in comparison with the metal performance shaders, gaussian blurs for example. But often it’s handier to use compute shaders as they are more general purpose and have certain advantages in comparison to hacking a system that was built to run games fast.